# Loadings of difference between two principal components?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python, pca, computational-statistics

I have a data set with 32 variables. Of those, I find two principal components. I then took the difference between principal components and I would like to find the loading of the difference between principal components. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: could you please explain what you mean by 'loading'?